# Can I load multiple xml files via XElement?

Tags: c#

I know in C sharp xml file can be loaded by using "XElement" object, but what in case user has to load multiple xml files. If not then what can be the done to do this. Any help is worthly appreciated...

Code :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.Xml;


namespace ConsoleApplication85
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            string path = @"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\configuration.xml";  // location of configuration.xml file.
            doc.Load(path);
            var nm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
            nm.AddNamespace("jb", "urn:jboss:domain:1.2");
            // Using foreach loop for specific Xmlnodes.
            foreach (XmlNode selectNode in doc.SelectNodes("jb:server/jb:system-properties/jb:property", nm))
            {
                if (selectNode.Attributes["name"].Value == "teststudio.pwd")  // tsuser1
                {
                    selectNode.Attributes["value"].Value = "new password";  // changes password value for "FTP_USER".
                    Console.WriteLine("tsuser1 passowrd changed");
                }

                if (selectNode.Attributes["name"].Value == "watson.git_pwd")   //github
                {
                    selectNode.Attributes["value"].Value = "new passwordx";  // changes password value for "FTP_READ_USER".
                    Console.WriteLine("github password changed");
                }
                if (selectNode.Attributes["name"].Value == "FTP_READ_PASS")   // wtsntro
                {
                    selectNode.Attributes["value"].Value = "new_passwordy";  // changes password value for "FTP_PASSWORD".
                    Console.WriteLine("wtsntro password changed");
                }
            }

            doc.Save(path);  // Save changes.
            Console.WriteLine("Password changed successfully");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? You can just call XElement.Load again for the other file and assign it to another variable...

Comment: Actually i have to load multiple xml files from multiple directories, after that want to do necessary modifications and finally save..

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: For one xml file i have a code that can do modification and finally save. Please see my edited code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("C:\\Temp\\", "*.xml");
foreach (string file in files)
{
    var element = XElement.Load(file);
    Console.Write(element);
}
```

Use `System.IO.Directory` classes with whild-cards to find all files you need, then process them in the loop. You can also make outer loop for multiple directories.

Comment: Thanks. But in my case *.xml files are placed in multiple directories.

Comment: I think this gives you enough info to forge proper solution for your specific case. How do you know which "multiple directories" you have to look for? Search all hard-disk?